# Thread interrupt in udp in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, udp

I have multiple devices that send udp packets and listen commands on 1024 port.
I want a udp server to listen continuously on port 1200.
But as soon as it receives any data on this port it should get interrupted to perform some other task.
I tried to understand it by my own but I am really confused.
If any one can help me understanding the concept of thread and interrupting and how can I interrupt it. I am mostly confused because I can not tell socket to listen to a specific IP.

I tried many things but then also I think my least knowledge about threading is stopping me from getting success. So I really need help now.

Here is the code for one connection at a time - I was calling it every seconds to receive data from each remote ip and update it on my page.

```
 Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
             SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    public byte[] serverSockets(String IPadd, byte[] dataToSend)
    {


        byte[] receivebytes = new byte[20] ;
        try
        {


            IPAddress iPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IPadd);
            int port = 1024;
            IPEndPoint iPEnd = new IPEndPoint(iPAddress, port);

            //Assign the any IP of the machine and listen on port number 1200
              IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1200);
            serverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
            serverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1000);
            serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
             ep = (EndPoint)iPEnd;

            serverSocket.SendTo(dataToSend, ep);
           // Thread.Sleep(1000);
            serverSocket.Receive(receivebytes);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            serverSocket.Dispose();

        }  

        return receivebytes;
    }
```

Here is the task I need to do - 
Need to create a thread that
Listen continuously on port 1200 and when data is received on that port it should do some task with that data and again start listening(that means that thread should start again). I dont know what steps should be followed to do that. How can I stop the thread in between to do some other task.

Comment: Do you really have an ASP.NET application listening for UDP connections? And what thread do you need to interrupt? That's not at all clear in your question.

Comment: I added the code I had before

Comment: "whenever receives data it gets interrupted to do some other task." - what does that even mean? What gets interrupted?

Comment: as you can see above, I was sending and receive from a client. But now I only want to listen continuously and that too from any client. the receiving port for my machine is fixed that is 1200.

Comment: I ask a question, and I get an answer for a question I didn't ask and no answer for the question I did ask. I give up.

Comment: @john.. I am sorry.. but I am trying to get clear of what my query is about.

Comment: But you're not explaining what you want to interrupt, and your code doesn't show the code of the thread you want to interrupt. It isn't even clear why you're not just handling the data in the thread you already have.

Comment: one by one John. I dont know much about threading. So I am not understanding how can I use that here.

Comment: Honestly, I think you're over-complicating things. If each connection has it's own thread, then you could use the `lock` keyword, or a `SemaphoreSlim` to synchronise access to a resource. Alternatively, if you have a separate thread (which it sounds like you do - which is probably overcomplicating things) processing the data, you could use a `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: Thank you John...This is really I wanted to know, a direction to work out things. I am going to try  this first and If I get any issues I will again ask.

Comment: Hi, I asked a new question because it got changed entirely now. here is the link for that- [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836657/udp-listener-c-sharp)

Comment: All changed to TCP now. Not using udp anymore. The changes are made in device itself to communicate on TCP